# Once the system has been started, is there any advantage in using systemd?

Tags: gentoo, systemd, init, sysvinit

I'm running Gentoo with the default SysV-style OpenRC init system. The boot time is short enough to not bother me. Is there any reason to try systemd?

Comment: No. It's not worse to use it.

Comment: See the copious documentation on [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), there you will see lots of reasons to run `systemd`, particularly in the management of daemons.

Comment: If Gnome 3.8 hadn't forced systemd migration, I would've happily kept living with OpenRC. systemd itself isn't bad though, it's the migration pain.

Comment: I wish you luck filtering through biased answers. :) I got fed up with systemd and use openrc now... it is the natural evolution of the sysvinit concept, so it works well and predictably, without bizarre side effects resulting from some spark of insanity the devs had and forced on the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther are multiple advantages of running systemd even after booting is done, some might interest you, some might not, a quick summary:

- Service Monitoring: systemd can monitor services and restart them on failure while most clients will not even notice the service has restarted.
- Clean management of services: in systemd your current environment variables do not influence the environment of a manually started service.
- Watchdog support: if you are on server hardware or an embedded platform (or even on some desktop platforms) you can have systemd talk to the hardware watchdog and trigger a reboot when critical services fail.
- Start less on startup: while this is mostly a boot speed improvement, it also minimizes memory usage since less services are loaded into memory.
- The journal: An easy and reliable logging daemon which logs more metadata than your classic syslogd, and allows you to easy filter on this information
- ...

for more information i redirect you to [the systemd homepage](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd)